# Kadena Pact Create Account Fails

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

Hi Kadena Pact developers,

I'm following `https://docs.kadena.io/build/frontend/pact-lang-api-cookbook#create-account` to create coin accounts.

`` getBalance(`sender00`) `` returns

```json
{
  "gas": 20,
  "result": {
    "status": "success",
    "data": 99998999.9999446
  },
  "reqKey": "AnmQHR9ciGruzwaV2LksjFANS8Mbr5UBuj26d2w4TLE",
  "logs": "wsATyGqckuIvlm89hhd2j4t6RMkCrcwJe_oeCYr7Th8",
  "metaData": {
    "publicMeta": {
      "creationTime": 1670018678,
      "ttl": 28000,
      "gasLimit": 600,
      "chainId": "0",
      "gasPrice": 1e-7,
      "sender": "368820f80c324bbc7c2b0610688a7da43e39f91d118732671cd9c7500ff43cca"
    },
    "blockTime": 1670018669855184,
    "prevBlockHash": "g5bNGUcMPQYC4klTi-D0QhsMBIT9oggVa_-Ea8hyQq4",
    "blockHeight": 1964
  },
  "continuation": null,
  "txId": null
}
```

I want to create another account using `sender00` keypairs, however it fails w/ error message

```
Validation failed for hash "iu9bake1-nzhfQuYoRCM_LggDBenBLDWjGf6o7d00kY": Attempt to buy gas failed with: : Failure: Tx Failed: read: row not found: 368820f80c324bbc7c2b0610688a7da43e39f91d118732671cd9c7500ff43cca
```

Here is the whole script and the `.env` file

```
SENDER00_PUBLIC=368820f80c324bbc7c2b0610688a7da43e39f91d118732671cd9c7500ff43cca
SENDER00_SECRET=251a920c403ae8c8f65f59142316af3c82b631fba46ddea92ee8c95035bd2898
```

Script file

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
import Pact from 'pact-lang-api';

const GAS_PRICE = 0.0000001;
const GAS_LIMIT = 400;
const TTL = 28000;
const NETWORK_ID = 'development'//'testnet04';
const CHAIN_ID = '0';
const API_HOST = `http://localhost:8080/chainweb/0.0/${NETWORK_ID}/chain/${CHAIN_ID}/pact`;

const creationTime = () => Math.round((new Date).getTime() / 1000) - 15;

async function getBalance(account) {
  const cmd = {
    networkId: NETWORK_ID,
    keyPairs: KEY_PAIR,
    pactCode: `(coin.get-balance "${account}")`,
    envData: {},
    meta: {
      creationTime: creationTime(),
      ttl: 28000,
      gasLimit: 600,
      chainId: CHAIN_ID,
      gasPrice: 0.0000001,
      sender: KEY_PAIR.publicKey
    }
  };

  const result = await Pact.fetch.local(cmd, API_HOST);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}


const KEY_PAIR = {
  'publicKey': `${process.env.SENDER00_PUBLIC}`,
  'secretKey': `${process.env.SENDER00_SECRET}`
}


async function createAccount(newAccount) {
  const cmd = {
    networkId: NETWORK_ID,
    keyPairs: KEY_PAIR,
    pactCode: `(coin.create-account "${newAccount}" (read-keyset "account-keyset"))`,
    envData: {
      "account-keyset": {
        keys: [
          // Drop the k:
          newAccount.substr(2)
        ],
        pred: "keys-all"
      },
    },
    meta: {
      creationTime: creationTime(),
      ttl: 28000,
      gasLimit: 600,
      chainId: CHAIN_ID,
      gasPrice: 0.0000001,
      sender: KEY_PAIR.publicKey
    }
  };

  const response = await Pact.fetch.send(cmd, API_HOST);
  if (!response.requestKeys)
  {
    return console.error(response)
  }
  console.log(`Request key: ${response.requestKeys[0]}`);
  console.log("Transaction pending...");
  const txResult = await Pact.fetch.listen(
    { listen: response.requestKeys[0] },
    API_HOST
  );
  console.log("Transaction mined!");
  console.log(txResult);
}


await getBalance(`sender00`) // OK
await createAccount(`testaccount`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `sender` in `cmd.meta.sender` to `sender00` and it worked.
Public keys and account names are different things I belive.

Comment: yes, don't use public keys as accountnames. Use principal account names to avoid security issues: https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pact-functions.html#create-principal